# Does anyone here know how to fix 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a game but then it gave me an error stating:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments.

By the way, I'm not the best at code so don't criticize me.

Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let skater = Skater(imageNamed: "skater") 
    //the line above showed the mistake

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero

        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        let xMid = frame.midX
        let yMid = frame.midY
        background.position = CGPoint(x: xMid, y: yMid)
        addChild(background)

        resetSkater()
        addChild(skater)
    }

    func resetSkater() {
        let skaterX = frame.midX / 2.0
        let skaterY = skater.frame.height / 2.0 + 64.0
        skater.position = CGPoint(x: skaterX, y: skaterY)
        skater.zPosition = 10
        skater.minimumY = skaterY
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is producing the error? you are passing arguments to a function that takes no arguments. There is no better way to describe it.

Comment: Where is code for Skater that take argument image name can you post that code?

Comment: is the `skater` returns the image ?

Comment: let skater = Skater(imageNamed: "skater")  is the line with the mistake @iOSArchitect.com

Comment: skater is an image in Xcode already @Suresh Mopidevi

Comment: ok can you share the code where you declare Skater. You must have declared a Skater class/struct right? Share that code

Comment: Im not familiar with game development and i didn't see `Skater` in Apple documentation. Please add a link of `skater` documentation for reference. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Coding iPhone Apps for Kids: A Playful Introduction to Swift** is a book available [here](https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=kAwqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=let%20skater%20%3D%20Skater(imageNamed:%20%22skater%22)&source=bl&ots=De7z49ZxME&sig=ACfU3U1sFEez4ehEh9KyH2boC_NuSxczCw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqxNPynOTmAhXLzoUKHe5iCmEQ6AEwCnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=let%20skater%20%3D%20Skater(imageNamed%3A%20%22skater%22)&f=false) [image] it will help you resolve issue

Comment: checkout the whole book ... how they are developing it from start